# BIND caches ENUM NAPTR records irrespective of TTL 0

Tags: redhat, bind

I am using BIND 9.6 to enable my application to act as a ENUM server. The ENUM server performs routing and responds to ENUM NAPTR records.

The NAPTR responses are sent with a TTL zero without any authority section. When I trigger a ENUM NAPTR load(using dig) with same digits, I could see some of the responses are not forwarded to the application for routing, instead handled by the BIND stack on its own.

The same behavior is not seen when the digits are different in a load, wherein the requests are all forwarded to the application for routing.

Is there any option available in BIND to enable the traffic to be forwarded always to the application? I tried setting the options max-cache-ttl and max-cache-size to zero, but didn't help. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Configure BIND as a forwarder for the zones in question, rather than a recursive resolver?  Also, are you positive that it's BIND that's caching the data and not the stub resolver on the client?